# helm uninstall succeeds but doesn't remove pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are running kubernetes 1.17 in azure and am able to install a release with no problem using helmsman v3.2.0. But for some reason when I run `--destroy` the command succeeds with no errors and when I do a `helm status <release>` it shows that the release has been deleted - but the pods are still showing up in the cluster/namespace.

helm - v3.2.4
kubectl - v1.18.6
helmsman - v3.2.0

Between the helmsman `--apply` and the `--destroy` nothing has changed so one should deploy (it does) and the other should destroy.

Likewise `helm uninstall <release>` succeeds but fails to remove any pods.

Comment: What do you mean what nothing has changed between apply and destroy. Did the pod get created in first place but helm ? Maybe the pod was not created by Helm...just asking

Comment: Yeah - the pods came up and were running. I mean I didn't change contexts or anything in my local environment.